# SQL join one row from a table to several rows from another one

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a `users` table and a `pic_urls` table, and I want to extract data from several users. Each user may have several rows in the `pic_urls` table. This is the SQL I have so far:

```sql
    SELECT
      users.id,
      users.firstname,
      users.lastname,
      pic_urls.url
    FROM users
    JOIN pic_urls
    ON users.id = pic_urls.user_id
    WHERE users.id != ?
```

So far I get all the info I want from the `users` table, but only the last row of `pic_urls` for each user. My question is, how to group several rows of the `pic_urls` table (a user usually have several pics) into an array or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname,
    ( 
        select json_arrayagg(pu.url)
        from pic_urls pu
        where pu.user_id = u.id
    ) all_urls
from users u
```

This aggregates all pic urls in a json array on each user row. Other aggregate options are available, such as `group_concat()` for string aggregation.